# Rule of Thumb for Evaluating Probabilities with Joint PDF's

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I realize that this is a broad question:

For seemingly related questions, I see that there are different approaches for evaluating certain types of questions, and I'm wondering if there is some general guidance/ insight regarding which types of problems necessitate certain approaches with some consistency. I'll provide examples below:

A. $f(x,y)=\frac{3}{4}x $ for $0\leq x \leq 2$, and $0 \leq y \leq 2-x$ find $P(X\geq 1)$. for this problem, the solution said to simply evaluate the double integral, $\int_1^2\int_0^{2-x}f(x,y)dydx$. This seems pretty straightforward, and it is what I would have originally thought to do from my probability class. However, then I see a problem like "B", and a different approach is specified in the solution

B.$f(x,y)=\frac{3}{4}(2-x-y)\text{ for } 0\leq X \leq 2 , \text{ and }  \leq y\leq 2$l AND ALSO $x+y\leq 2 $, and the problem asks you to find $E[X+Y]$  At first glance I thought to do LOTUS, that is $\int\int h(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy$, but this was wrong and ketp giving me nonsense answers. Instead, the solution proposed solving this by finding nothing that if $X+Y\leq 2 $, then $X\leq 2-Y $, and then finding the marginal distribution of X and then calculating E[X], via $f_X(x)=\int f(x,y)dy=\int ^{2-x}_0\frac{3}{4}(2-x-y)dy=\frac{3}{8}(2-x)^2$, and then $E[X]=\int x\cdot f(x)dx=\int ^2_0 x\cdot \frac{3}{8}(2-x)^2dx=\frac{1}{2}$.

My question is: Why is it done one way in one context and a different way in another? Is there some rule I can rely on to make this determination?

Comment: For B, LOTUS should work. If it kept giving you wrong answers, then you must’ve gotten the limits of integration wrong. In fact, finding the marginal of $X$ first is what you do implicitly when you apply LOTUS to calculate $E[X+Y]$, so I would say that the two methods you propose aren’t really different.

Comment: Thank you! However, towards more context, let's say I was trying to save time (I'm studying for a standardized test), is there a set of circumstance in which I could rely on just using the marginal, as a shortcut?

Comment: For  B. we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X+Y] &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} (x+y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf d(x\times y)\\
&= \int_0^2\int_0^{2-x} \frac34(x+y)(2-x-y)\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx\\
&= 1.
\end{align}

Comment: @Math1000. Thank you, but I don't understand what this is demonstrating...